# Is giving elements an id within a html template okay?

Tags: javascript, html, templates, dynamic, element

I feel like the answer is an obvious 'no', but I've seen it done in tutorials and am curious if the side effects are what one would expect.

HTML 4/5 specify that ids should be unique document wide, but are still forgiving on the matter. How might the browser respond to dynamically injected elements that may have been given ids in their respective template? Is it encouraged to just use classes for elements in templates? If ids are okay, then how is it handled by the browser?

Answer (score 1):

Ids are unique which is used to apply styling or some particular task for that particular element.

when we inject dynamically the html structure that ID name on element should be unique then only that styling and the manipulation will work

You can insert as many Ids in the Single page and the browser will handles that properly depending the elements which you will inject

Remember that ID are use for only one tag.so whatever will be the styling of manipulation will added that will work for that ID only.